# Reset used CSS properties set by parent element for a modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap's `alert` feature to annotate an HTML table based on some statuses. In each table cell, there is also a modal window. The modal window inherits the CSS properties set by `<td>` element using `alert*` features:

```
<td class="alert alert-block alert-success">
  <a>Modal Link</a>
  <div>Modal Content<div>
</td>
```

So, when the modal displays it actually displays with the colors set by the type of `alert` which is already set by the parent `td`. Is there anyway to reset the CSS properties for the modal `div`?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a style just for that `<div>` that overrides all the properties defined for  `.alert`. However, I usually put the modal `<div>` outside the `<table>`.

```
<table>
  ...
  <td class="alert alert-block alert-success">
    <a>Modal Link</a>
  </td>
  ...
</table>
<div>Modal Content<div>
```

The modal `<div>` is not going to be shown inside the `<td>` so no sense in putting it there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe, I should have given more context. The HTML is rendered using Apache Wicket. Each modal is generated based on a model on the server with some kind of iteration. Since the iteration is somehow expensive, it cannot be afforded to separate the generation of modal and the table cell itself.

Comment: Then you could add a new style for the `<div>` that overrides the color of the `.alert`. You could define it as `.alert div { color: ... }` in your stylesheet